# Big O Time Complexity of While Loops

Tags: while-loop, big-o

I am a bit confused about the time complexity, in the case of two seperate while loops.
I am aware that the code:

```
while(i<N){
     code
    while(k<N){
       code
    }
}
```

will have a complexity of O(n^2)
What about the case where we don't have nested loops, though?

```
while(i<N){
}
while(k<N){
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you run two loops, one after the other. If they both perform *n* iterations, then your code performs *2n* loop iterations in total.

Now, *2n = O(2n) = **O(n)*** (by the properties of [big-O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)), so that is your time complexity.